# Suppressing the inline variable warning

Tags: c++

**Background**
We are trying to "borrow" some code which uses an inline static variable.  The code complies, without any warnings, with a C++17 compiler.  However with a lower version compiler it gives the following warning:
`warning: inline variables are only available with ‘-std=c++17’ or ‘-std=gnu++17’`

We have been able to suppress the waning with a command-line switch but I wanted to know if there is a way to refactor the code for suppressing the warning.

I have been able to reproduce the issue with the following sample code:

---

**Sample Code**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class MyClass {
    T a;
public:
    void initialize(T value) {
        a = value;
    }
    
   friend ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const MyClass &obj) {
       out << "Hello world " << obj.a << "!!!";
       return out;
   }
   
   /*inline*/ static MyClass<T> SENTINEL_VALUE;
   // Currently we have the undefined reference linker error
   // If we uncomment /*inline*/ we get the warning
   //
   // I know that static class member has to instantiated before
   // main() but in this case I am not sure how to do that
};


int main()
{
    MyClass<int>::SENTINEL_VALUE.initialize(56);
    cout << MyClass<int>::SENTINEL_VALUE << endl;

    MyClass<int> myObj;
    myObj.initialize(42);
    cout << myObj << endl;
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to define the variable as usual in a cpp file? (outside the main function)

Comment: Using C++17 features that don't exist in prior versions like C++14, C++11, or C++98 will usually have unsatisfactory results.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk yes I tried a few things but it just did not seem to work.

Comment: Usually `initialize` would be replaced by a constructor and you could then write `template<> MyClass<int> MyClass<int>::SENTINEL_VALUE(56);` at top level in exactly one source file.  Example: https://godbolt.org/z/oez56rYGE

Comment: ***I tried a few things but it just did not seem to work.*** If you attempted to do what the error message told you to do, maybe your compiler is just too old and does not support c++17.

Answer (score 1):

Inlined static member is supported only since C++17, hence the compiler's warning. There is no sense in suppressing it, if you use something prior to C++17.
All you need is to initialize your static member (within the same *header* file):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class MyClass {
    T a;
public:
    void initialize(T value) {
        a = value;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const MyClass &obj) {
        out << "Hello world " << obj.a << "!!!";
        return out;
    }

    static MyClass<T> SENTINEL_VALUE;
};

template <typename T>
MyClass<T> MyClass<T>::SENTINEL_VALUE{};
```

So, for instance, `cout << MyClass<int>::SENTINEL_VALUE << endl;` outputs `Hello world 0!!!`.

Initializing a static member of a class template within a header file is allowed and will not lead to multiple definitions error.
**Note, that this applies only to member variables of class templates (or member variable templates).**

Comment: It’s important to note that this applies only to member variables of class **templates** (or member variable templates).

Comment: @DavisHerring I did mentioned that in the last paragraph

Comment: Sure, but that seems like a coincidence in the context of the question, and so a stronger statement that the other cases require a source-file definition seems warranted.

Comment: @DavisHerring I modified the answer